# Flattening duplicate rows with additional unique data

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need to flatten a row similarly to what is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748781/flatten-multiple-rows-containing-different-data-but-with-a-common-reference-in).

Example:

```
Topic1 Remark1
Topic1 Remark2
Topic2 Remark1
Topic2 Remark2
Topic2 Remark3
```

into

```
Topic1 Remark1 Remark2
Topic2 Remark1 Remark2 Remark3
```

I am looking for an updated and easier solution to this. I was hoping i could do this on a spreadsheet program like excel without having to resort to complicated scripts.

Comment: Just for information, are the rows unique or could you have two with the same values like 'Topic1 Remark1 / Topic1 Remark1' and if so would you want to keep both of them? (BTW what you are doing is basically a pivot, but I appreciate that a standard pivot table isn't quite what you want).

Comment: I just need one. Essentially i need all remarks in one row, grouped by topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with two very simple formulas.

Get the unique values of the topic column:

`=unique(A:A)`

and then filter the remarks for each topic:

`=transpose(filter(B:B,A:A=E1))`

[image: example]

Comment: For some weird reason I am getting the #Name? error when simply doing unique A1:A

Comment: @DottoreM to be honest I can't reproduce your issue. Can you try just `unique(A:A)` then?

Comment: or even try `unique(A1:A5)` where 5 can be your preferred range @DottoreM

Answer (score 3):

In addition, for a single formula solution, you can try

```
=arrayformula(trim(split(unique(A2:A)&"/"&transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(A2:A))=A2:A)*len(A2:A),B2:B&"/",),,rows(A2:A))), "/")))
```

Change ranges to suit.

[image]